# Perspective transform (warp) of an image

Tags: c++, image, transformation, perspective

I'm stuck trying to get perspective transformation to work.

I want to draw an image so it fits 4 given points. It's something like you have in Photoshop and it's used to change the perspective of image (see image below).

I have an image in byte array and I'm not using any additional libraries.
Everything I've found so far was either for OpenCV or didn't do what I wanted.

I have found some open-source program PhotoDemon and it does exactly what I want, and [there is a code for that](https://github.com/tannerhelland/PhotoDemon/blob/master/Forms/VBP_FormPerspective.frm). I was trying to get it to work for many hours but it gives me completly weird results (second line on the image below).

Could someone provide me with some code or step-by-step math of what and how to do or even just a pseudo-code. I'm a little bit sick of it. It seems easy but I need some help.

[image: Image of my goal]

Comment: What you are saying is contradictory: "it does exactly what I want" and "it gives me completely weird results". Did you modify the code in any way ? There is something wrong in the way the abscissas are resampled (as if there was arithmetic overflow), the ordinates seem ok.

Comment: Well, indeed it sounds contradictory. What I mean is that the code is supposed to do exactly what I want (and it works in author's program:PhotoDemon) but when I use it, it doesn't.

The code was written in Visual Basis and as a part of bigger project, so of course I had to modify it to c++ and as universal one.
But I check the code so many times, however there are some things I'm still not sure about, that is why I'm lookin for another source here.

Comment: I dont have any code but Texture mapping should work. Give a look at it.

Comment: Check what changes you made when migrating to C++; especially the data types. Fixing the bug should involve less effort than reworking from scratch, you are in the last 1% of the solution.

Comment: Ok, I finally managed to solve the problem. 
The problem was with rounding double to int when reading source pixels' colors. 

Feel a little bit stupid with making such simple mistake, but working long can dull prudence ;) Thanx for your replies.